# Spring AOP args

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I Have a problem with Spring AOP. I want to get the object of Student in a Pointcut. But my JoinPoints can have this object in any priority. 
Look at the snipped below code for the two different JoinPoints and the Pointcut that I have Created:

```
public Student createStudent(String s, Student student) {...}
public Student updateStudent(Student student, String s) {...}

@Before("args(..,com.hadi.student.Student)") 
public void myAdvice(JoinPoint jp) {
    Student student = null;
    for (Object o : jp.getArgs()) {
        if (o instanceof Student) {
            student = (Student) o;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works only for the first JoinPoint. So the question is how to create a Pointcut that will be executed for any situation of Student in input parameter. 
I could not use below code, it throws runtimeException:
`@Before("args(..,com.hadi.student.Student,..)")`

I make the code easy to understand, actually my Poincut is so bigger than this. So please just answer with **args** way.

Answer (score 6):

I have answered similar questions several times, e.g. here:

- [AspectJ pointcut expression match parameter annotations at any position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15605403/1082681)
- [How to write an Aspect pointcut based on an annotated parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29714549/1082681)

Your case is a bit simpler because you just want to extract a parameter and not its annotation. So along the lines of those other two answers you would use a pointcut like this:

```java
@Before("execution(* *(.., com.hadi.student.Student, ..))")
```

and then extract the argument in your advice via iterating over `thisJoinPoint.getArgs()` and checking for the right parameter type. This is slower and uglier than directly binding a method argument to an advice parameter via `args()`, but your only option for parameters in arbitrary positions because `args(.., Student, ..)` will yield an "ambiguous argument binding" error. This is because both AspectJ and Spring AOP cannot decide what should happen if there is more than one `Student` argument in your method. Which one should they choose?

Here is an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in AspectJ (no Spring required, but works the same way there):

**Helper class and driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Student {
  private String name;

  public Student(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Student [name=" + name + "]";
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public void doSomething() {}

  public Student createStudent(String s, Student student) {
    return student;
  }

  public Student updateStudent(Student student, String s) {
    return student;
  }

  public void marryStudents(Student student1, Student student2) {}

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application application = new Application();
    application.doSomething();
    application.createStudent("x", new Student("John Doe"));
    application.updateStudent(new Student("Jane Doe"), "y");
    // What happens if we have multiple Student parameters?
    application.marryStudents(new Student("Jane"), new Student("John"));
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

import de.scrum_master.app.Student;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
  @Before("execution(* *(.., de.scrum_master.app.Student, ..))")
  public void interceptMethodsWithStudentArgs(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    for(Object arg : thisJoinPoint.getArgs()) {
      if (!(arg instanceof Student))
        continue;
      Student student = (Student) arg;
      System.out.println("  " + student);
    }
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
execution(Student de.scrum_master.app.Application.createStudent(String, Student))
  Student [name=John Doe]
execution(Student de.scrum_master.app.Application.updateStudent(Student, String))
  Student [name=Jane Doe]
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.marryStudents(Student, Student))
  Student [name=Jane]
  Student [name=John]
```