# pointcut expression to parse @ModelAttribute as method parameter

Tags: java, aspectj, modelattribute, pointcut

I have a @ModelAttribute(key) defined in the @controllerAdvice and i am uisng the same model attribute in multiple controller methods as method parameter because the (key) will be available throughout all the controllers.

I am adding the attribute (key) in controller class like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String list(final Model model,@ModelAttribute("key") final boolean key) { 
...
...
}
```

I want to intercept all the controller methods which has `@ModelAttribute("key")` as the method parameter.

My aspect file looks like this.

```
@Component
@Aspect
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class myAspectclass {

@Pointcut("execution(public * *(.., @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute(boolean key)))")
          public void methodWithAnnotatedParameter() {}

@Around("methodWithAnnotatedParameter()")
public String blahMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint PJP){

blah blah

....
}
```

However my server startup fails saying

> [tomcat:launch] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting 'name pattern' at character position 97
>
> [tomcat:launch] execution(public * *(.., @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute(boolean key), ..))

I am unable to understand the error in this case... am i doing something wrong syntactically ?

Note: My `ModelAttribute(key)` does not have any specific position in the parameter list

Referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765996/aspectj-pointcut-expression-match-parameter-annotations-at-any-position) answer:

Comment: Yes, your syntax is illegal. This is what the error message means. Question: Have you noticed that this annotation according to [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html) has three parameters, `boolean binding`, `String name` and `String value`? There is no `boolean key`. Where did you get that idea from?

Answer (score 0):

Here is s stand-alone AspectJ example (not a Spring application, but aspect syntax should be the same).

**Driver application:**

As you can see, there are several methods with and without `@ModelAttribute` parameter annotations, one of them even with two annotated parameters (whether it makes sense or not, but it is just an example).

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;

public class Application {
  public String list(Model model, @ModelAttribute("key") boolean key) {
    return "x";
  }

  public String foo(Model model, @ModelAttribute("key") boolean key, @ModelAttribute(name = "key") String text) {
    return "x";
  }

  public String bar(@ModelAttribute(name = "key") int number) {
    return "x";
  }

  public String zot(Model model, @ModelAttribute("XXX") boolean key) {
    return "x";
  }

  public String baz(Model model, boolean key, String text) {
    return "x";
  }

  public String bla(@ModelAttribute("XXX") int number) {
    return "x";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Model model = new Model() {
      @Override public Model mergeAttributes(Map<String, ?> arg0) { return null; }
      @Override public boolean containsAttribute(String arg0) { return false; }
      @Override public Map<String, Object> asMap() { return null; }
      @Override public Model addAttribute(String arg0, Object arg1) { return null; }
      @Override public Model addAttribute(Object arg0) { return null; }
      @Override public Model addAllAttributes(Map<String, ?> arg0) { return null; }
      @Override public Model addAllAttributes(Collection<?> arg0) { return null; }
    };
    Application application = new Application();
    application.list(model, true);
    application.foo(model, true, "hey");
    application.bar(11);
    application.zot(model, true);
    application.baz(model, true, "hey");
    application.bla(11);
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

The aspect matches all method executions having at least one parameter with a `@ModelAttribute` annotation. The pointcut would be enough if you only want to finde those methods, regardless of annotation parameter values. But as you said, you only want to match the ones which have `value = "key"`, we need to use reflection in order to look into the annotations themselves and filter out the unwanted ones.

Another complication that according to [`@ModelAttribute` JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html), parameters `name` and `value` are aliases for each other, i.e. we also need to check both parameters' values in order to get it completely right.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;

@Aspect
@Component
public class ModelAttributeInterceptor {
  @Pointcut("execution(public * *(.., @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute (*), ..))")
  public void methodWithAnnotatedParameter() {}

  @Around("methodWithAnnotatedParameter()")
  public String blahMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) thisJoinPoint.getSignature();
    Annotation[][] annotationMatrix = methodSignature.getMethod().getParameterAnnotations();
    boolean foundModelAttribute = false;
    for (Annotation[] annotations : annotationMatrix) {
      for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
        if (!(annotation instanceof ModelAttribute))
          continue;
        ModelAttribute modelAttribute = (ModelAttribute) annotation;
        if ("key".equals(modelAttribute.value()) || "key".equals(modelAttribute.name())) {
          if (!foundModelAttribute) {
            System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
            foundModelAttribute = true;
          }
          System.out.println("  " + modelAttribute);
        }
      }
    }
    return (String) thisJoinPoint.proceed();
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.list(Model, boolean))
  @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute(name=, value=key, binding=true)
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.foo(Model, boolean, String))
  @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute(name=, value=key, binding=true)
  @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute(name=key, value=, binding=true)
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.bar(int))
  @org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute(name=key, value=, binding=true)
```